# Error con FOSJsRoutingBundle y KnpSnappyBundle

Tags: symfony2

Estoy utilizando la versión 2.3 de Symfony y KnpSnappyBudle para generar plantillas de Twig de html a pdf. Tuve un problema al añadir imágenes, pero vi la solucion por internet que utilizando request en la url se solucionaba.

Ejemplo: `src= ” {{ app.request.scheme ~’://’ ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset(‘img/logo.png’) }} ”.`

Ahora tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar. Estoy utilizando FOSJsRoutingBundle para generar rutas y en la plantilla que convierto a pdf con KnpSnappyBundle tengo lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
```

Con ésta línea al generar el pdf me da el siguiente error(el mismo error que me daba con las imagenes antes de usar request en las rutas):

```
The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
[=======> ] 13%
[==========> ] 18%
[==========================> ] 44%
[============================> ] 47%
[==============================> ] 50%
[==============================> ] 50%
[===========================================> ] 73%
[==============================================> ] 78%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
"stdout: ""
command: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality --page-size 'A4' --viewport-size '‘1024x768’' '/tmp/knp_snappy576ad837d24a82.40556276.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy576ad837d25009.94614572.pdf'.
```

¿Habría alguna forma de cambiar eso para que funcione? Estoy empezando en esto, así que agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('bundles/cidisapsi/bootstrap-4.3.1/css/dashboard.css')) }}"/>
```

llama a los assets de los css, imagenes y etc con absolute_url. Así funciona y muestra el css y las imagenes tal cual se ven en las vistas twig.

Comment: Te recomendaría que le dieras al usuario una explicación de como solucionaste, su problema, para que en futuras publicaciones, se puedan consultar